# Stamps of passport gone

Tags: passports, passport-stamps

I left my passport in my jeans pocket to wash. The passport is not damaged but the stamps are gone. I'm in Korea and the stamp mark from my arrival can be barely seen. Will it be a problem going through the custom?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26404/4868

Answer (score 9):

Personally I would visit the Immigration office (or at least call) and talk to them about the issue.  They may not care, they may want to re-stamp your passport or something else.  But better to resolve this now, rather than risk missing your flight because of delays while they deal with it at departure.

Answer (score 4):

Even if your country is ok with it (or the country of visit), the airline can stop you from travelling if they considered your passport to be damaged.

Just today, there was an article about [Jetstar barring a passenger from travelling with a tattered passport](http://www.stuff.co.nz/travel/travel-troubles/75406189/man-denied-boarding-on-jetstar-flight-to-new-zealand-because-of-dogeared-passport).

The passenger had confirmed with the embassy that his passport was ok, but it's also up to the airline to confirm that it meets the standards.

Comment: The passport in that article was beyond "damaged", I am surprised anyone would accept it.  That's a passport you frame and hang with your vacation photos to prove how much your traveled ;-)

Comment: @Tom the poll on that page, 2/3 of people reckon it's not damaged, as did his embassy and Singapore Air. Go figure :)

Comment: I can't imagine the airline refusing to let him return home for lacking an entry stamp. If he was leaving his native country with a damaged passport, sure, it could be an issue, but returning home?

Comment: @neubert like the linked article says, there's no international definition of 'damaged', so it's likely up to the agent's interpretation. I'd be confident I could talk my way out of a problem as long as it's scannable still.

Comment: @MarkMayo - Polls by newspapers are about as scientific as spinning the bottle ;-)

Comment: @Tom wasn't trying to claim it was scientific! You offered an opinion and I was merely showing that others felt it was fine. Although I suspect the article probably swayed a few of them.

Comment: @MarkMayo - I was joking with ya ... not belittlin' ya.